# Mosfet blows on high load using gate driver

Tags: mosfet, switching, mosfet-driver, high-current, powermosfet

I am using LM5060 from TI for switching big modular N channel MOSFET in SOT-227 package (IXFN420N10T) for relative high 100-200A loads.

On small loads like 10-20A it was working fine then we tried a bigger resistive load of around 50A and it was working completely fine when first connected when the gate was switched it was opened up and current flew and worked just fine. But then the gate of MOSFET didn't work anymore always opened.

Our schematic is based on the reference from datasheet with added 0.01uF capacitor on the gate.

Maybe someone does know why mosfet get's blown? It supposes to handle 420A and at 50A it blows (not literally but the gate doesn't work anymore)

EDIT: Here is schematic as asked

EDIT2: At first I saw in documentation that Vgate is like 12V so it was within the range, and now I see in further documentation it writes this but I don't really understand if I am understood correctly:

> A charge pump provides bias voltage above the input and output voltage to enhance the N-channel MOSFET
>   gate. When the system voltage is initially applied and both EN and UVLO are above their respective thresholds,
>   the GATE pin is charged by the 24-µA (typical) current source. During normal operating conditions, the GATE pin
>   voltage is clamped to approximately 16.8 V above the OUT pin (i.e. VGS) by an internal zener

So if I understood it charges voltage VIN - 16.8V ?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the gate voltage is within spec?

Comment: Is this all you can tell us?

Comment: Schematic or it didn't happen. Your schematic, not a copy of a datasheet or app-npte.

Comment: Well, it's simple. You did something wrong. Of course, if you're not going to tell us exactly what you did, there's no way we can help.

Comment: How did you protect gate from excessive LdI/dt

Comment: I added schematic

Comment: TonyStewartEEsince1975 If you have any more question I can answer. I don't really know about LdI/dT protection so I can't answer that for you

Comment: show layout and Rca heatsink

Comment: The layout is pretty simple chip is on separate board and gate wire goes out on mosfet VIN, VOUT wires too. Mosfet is attached to massive heatsink.

Comment: @C_Elegans I updated question regarding gate voltage

Comment: What is the input voltage and what was the load when it stopped working?

Comment: Can you measure Vgs impedance?

Comment: 42V and around 50A it was around 1 ohm resistance wire submerged in water to cool it.

Comment: You mean from gate to ground?

Comment: At 30V and simple mosfet we had on hand Vgate was 42V so I guess the problem is that gate voltage is too high?

Comment: you applied 42V to Vgs?

Comment: I did not applied, but LM5060 did :D I and think this is the problem right? If that mosfet is 20V max on VGS and VIN was 42V so ~15V more and it would be around 60V on gate which killed gate I guess right? So zener diode would solve this problem right?

Comment: But now I was reading about high side n channel mosfet switching and Vgate volgate is not referenced to ground anymore but to source so it means it needs something like 15V on top of source voltage right? So 42V on 30V should be okay right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of circuit generates a ramp for the gate voltage which causes the output voltage to ramp. This limits inrush current due to capacitive loads. But there is a down side, while the voltage is ramping the MOSFET is operating in linear mode and subjected to stress of V*I. In your case the MOSFET you have chosen has Ciss of 47 nF which dwarfs the 0.01 uF you have added so the rise time will be about 100 ms. So half through the ramp, the MOSFET will be dissipating 441W (21V * 21A).
There is a curve in the datasheet called SOA (safe operating area). At Vds of 20V the MOSFET can withstand 30A for 100 ms. So it possible you have exceeded SOA. It might worth putting a scope on the gate and source to see what the rise time actually is. You could try it with a load that is somewhat lower to see if it survives.